# Drop down textbox in Tcl/Tk

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

1. Here is a Database :

   ```
   apple     20
   mango     45
   banana    30
   ```

   I want to get these fruits name in a drop down text box.

   ---
2. I have a text field to add fruits name into the Database.

   ```
   label .l1 -text "Fruits :" 
   entry .e1
   pack .l1 .e1
   label .l2 -text "Store :"
   entry .e2
   pack .l2 .e2
   button .b1 -text "OK" -command save
   pack .b1

   proc save {} {
       set fpR [read [open "abcd.txt"]]
       set fp [open "abcd.txt" w]
       puts $fp "$fpR\n[.e1 get]   [.e2 get]"
   }
   ```

   After adding new data without closing the GUI:

   ```
   apple     20
   mango     45
   banana    30
   guava     10
   ```

Now, after adding a fruit without closing the GUI, how can I get it in that drop down box ?

Comment: Add some code, what have you tried?

Comment: Code added @schlenk. Please help

Comment: “Drop-down textboxes” are called a [`ttk::combobox`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_combobox.htm) in Tk…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet (with your code changed as little as possible) which uses a combobox and adds fruits to it:

```
package require Tk

ttk::combobox .combo
pack .combo

# Set up proc to populate combobox
proc refresh_combo {} {
  # Set up channel to read file
  set fin [open abcd.txt r]
  # Get all fruit names in a single list
  set fruitList [lmap x [split [read $fin] "\n"] {if {$x != ""} {lindex $x 0} else {continue}}]
  close $fin
  .combo configure -values $fruitList
}

refresh_combo

label .l1 -text "Fruits :" 
entry .e1
pack .l1 .e1
label .l2 -text "Store :"
entry .e2
pack .l2 .e2
button .b1 -text "OK" -command add_fruits
pack .b1

proc add_fruits {} {
    # Open file to append new fruits
    set fp [open "abcd.txt" a]
    puts $fp "[.e1 get]   [.e2 get]"
    close $fp
    refresh_combo
}
```

Though it would probably be better to have your values tab delimited (or some other appropriate delimiter) in your text file. If you really want a database, you might look into [sqlite](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TdbcsqliteCmd/tdbc_sqlite3.htm) which makes retrieval and updates easier.